# URL with URL parameters gets concatenated in browsers

Tags: javascript, url

I have the following code:

```
const url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?redirect_uri=' +
                    encodeURIComponent('https://dev.mysite.com/google_oauth2/') + 
                    '&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file&client_id=myclientid'

window.open(url, "", "width=700,height=500")
```

And the super-strange behaviour is that if I clear the browser history and run this code for the first time, it works fine, BUT THEN if I run for the second and subsequent times, the urls gets concatenated and I see

> https://dev.mysite.com/google_oauth2/?code=mycode&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file

instead of

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?redirect_uri=https://dev.mysite.com%2Fgoogle_oauth2%&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file&client_id=myclientid

Does anyone know why this happens ?

BTW, I am using React.JS, but I don't think it has something to do with this...

**Resolved. Was a Google-specific issue**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use a more appropriate URL and URLSearchParams for such purpose: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams
and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

So your code would be:

```
const url = new URL('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth')
url.searchParams.append('redirect_uri', 'https://dev.mysite.com/google_oauth2/');
url.searchParams.append('scope', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file');
url.searchParams.append('client_id', 'myclientid');
```

And `url.href` would be:

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysite.com%2Fgoogle_oauth2%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.file&client_id=myclientid

Comment: anyway, your suggestion is valuable per se, so I rewrote the code as per your example, but the issue still persists :(

Comment: I see for a second the original url, but then after a second it gets concatendated

Comment: I've created a sandbox for this with your code, but I can't reproduce the described issue. https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-fast-hvrib Did you use any specific environment? Or could you make a sandbox with described problem?